# ServletContext object null in Spring Service Implementation class

Tags: java, spring, servlets, servletcontextlistener

I've a contextlistener where I'm setting the properties attribute to the ServletContext object. and in one of implementation class, I'm trying to get the attribute. But the servletcontext object returns null here. Here is my code

### ContextListener

```
public class LoadProperties implements ServletContextListener {

private static Properties properties = null;
private static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(LoadProperties.class);  

@Override
public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent arg0) { }

@Override
public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent event) {

    ClassLoader classLoader = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
    InputStream input = classLoader.getResourceAsStream("db.properties");
    properties = new Properties();
    try {
        properties.load(input);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        logger.error(e);
    }       
    ServletContext ctx=event.getServletContext();  
    ctx.setAttribute("properties", properties);   --> ctx has values now
}
}
```

Impl class

--

```
@Component
public class BBServiceImpl implements BBService{

    private static Properties properties = null;
    @Autowired
    ServletContext ctx;

     public BBServiceImpl () {
          properties =(Properties) ctx.getAttribute("properties"); --> ctx is null here. 
     }
}
```

How can I get the value of properties here

Comment: Why this contraption? Why not simply let Spring load the properties? But to answer your question of course it will be `null`. How can something be auto wired in an object that is still being constructed...

Comment: But, I require in this way. How can I do ?Since the contextlistener has set the attribute, it should be available in the total application right?

Comment: Again how can something be injected into an object that isn't even constructed yet (there is no instance of `BBServiceImpl` which spring can use to inject dependencies in). Why do you require it this way you are basically attaching your whole application to the servlet environment. Instead I suggest to use Spring to load the `db.properties` and use the regular approach to read properties.

Comment: @M.Deinum, Thank you for the response